# Why is Gatsby arrow function not able to see a value passed in props where value is derived from promise?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-hooks

Can someone please explain why the value of `key` within the arrow function is undefined:

```
// in parent component
const Parent = () => {

        const [key, setKey] = useState<string>();

        // this contains an expensive function we only wish to execute once on first load
        useEffect(() => {
            // has some promise that will call within a `then()`            
            setKey(someVal);
        }, []};


    // within render
    < MyComponent key={key}/>
}


// within child component
interface Props {
    key: string;
}

const MyComponent = ({key}: Props) => {

    // this works, I can see the correct value `someVal`
    console.log("value when rendered: " + key);

    const callback = () => {
        // this isn't working, key is undefined
        console.log("value within callback: " + key);
    }

  // within render, when something calls callback(), key is undefined, why?

  
}
```

I can see that `key` has a value when the render is called, but `key` is undefined. I've tried using `let callback =` instead of `const`, but no luck. How do I access `key` please?

Comment: I would expect the destructured parameter to be in the closure. Can you give a [mre], how is the callback invoked? And why would let make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

In React, `key` is a reserved prop name.

> [...] attempting to access this.props.key from a component (i.e., the render function or `propTypes`) is not defined

https://reactjs.org/warnings/special-props.html

Which is probably the reason why it doesn't work in subsequent renders — I'm surprised that it worked in the first render at all!

This works fine:

```js
// https://codepen.io/d4rek/pen/PoZRWQw

import { nanoid } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/nanoid/nanoid.js'

const Child = ({ id }) => {
  console.log(`within component: ${id}`)
  const cb = () => console.log(`in callback: ${id}`)
  return <button onClick={cb}>Click me</button>
}

const Parent = () => {
  const [id, setId] = React.useState(null)
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setId(nanoid(6))
  }, [])
  
  return (<Child id={id} />)
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.body)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React, { useCallback } from 'react';

const callback = useCallback(() => {
    // this isn't working, key is undefined
    console.log("value within callback: " + key);
}, [key]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why yours is not working: props are bound to `this` but the callback as you defined it has its own scope and hence has its own `this`. So you need to provide the value to that scope. You can do it by using local state of the component. Since there are some nice hooks in React to make that easy you should use them to memorize the callback:

`React.useCallback(() =>{console.log(key);}, [key]);`

Note the dependency array that updates the callback when `key` changes. Here the scoping is fine.